# Ways to find records based on their first letter awk Unix using variable

Tags: unix, awk

```
awk -F":" -v var="$letterinput" '$3 ~ /^$var/{printf"%-s\n",$3}' NSN_DATA
```

this is what i have come up with so far. I can get it to work with switch out ^var with ^A but i need it to allow the user to set letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to

```
awk -F: -v var="$letterinput" '$3 ~ "^"var {printf"%-s\n",$3}' NSN_DATA
```

Comment: Thank you! This works! I assume that in the future if i want to use any modifiers (i.e ^) in my awk statements with variables i just have to surround them with " "?

Comment: yes string regex is required for variables, `/value/` is only for fixed literals/patterns.